# How to show line number when executing bash script

Tags: linux, bash, testing

I have a test script which has a lot of commands and will generate lots of output, I use `set -x` or `set -v` and `set -e`, so the script would stop when error occurs. However, it's still rather difficult for me to locate which line did the execution stop in order to locate the problem.
Is there a method which can output the line number of the script before each line is executed?
Or output the line number before the command exhibition generated by `set -x`?
Or any method which can deal with my script line location problem would be a great help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

You mention that you're already using `-x`.  The variable `PS4` denotes the value is the prompt printed before the command line is echoed when the `-x` option is set and defaults to `:` followed by space.

You can change `PS4` to emit the `LINENO` (The line number in the script or shell function currently executing).

For example, if your script reads:

```
$ cat script
foo=10
echo ${foo}
echo $((2 + 2))
```

Executing it thus would print line numbers:

```
$ PS4='Line ${LINENO}: ' bash -x script
Line 1: foo=10
Line 2: echo 10
10
Line 3: echo 4
4
```

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips (alternate: [web archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230401201759/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/debuggingtips)) gives the ultimate `PS4` that would output everything you will possibly need for tracing:

```
export PS4='+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'
```

Comment: I wonder why no one mentions this for "How to debug shell scripts?" . This is far better than just `echo`

Comment: @VusP Agreed, unnecessary `echo` statements are best avoided.

Comment: You can even output nanosecond times, although at the cost of a considerable slow-down: `PS4='Line $LINENO @ $(date +%s.%N): ' bash -x script`

Comment: I can't help but feel that `-x` *should* print line numbers. Or, maybe -`nx` *should* include line numbers. For me, its one of those "WTF" moments...

Comment: Man, I wish I knew about that PS4 concoction sooner... It would have saved me so many headaches

Comment: `\033[0;33m+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}):\033[0m ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'` for some colors

Comment: How do you use it with functions?

Comment: `export PS4='+(${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}:${LINENO}): ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }'`
for when `BASH_SOURCE` doesn't tell you the name of the running script.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for providing such an important debugging tool. Why this isn't the standard for "set -x" is beyond me.  If I could give you a hundred "Useful" clicks, I would.

It appears that the ++ signs indicate nesting level within the bash script.

Comment: first char of PS4 should be a symbol like `+` because it is repeated on nesting

Answer (score 51):

In Bash, `$LINENO` contains the line number where the script currently executing.

If you need to know the line number where the function was called, try `$BASH_LINENO`. Note that this variable is an array.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash       

function log() {
    echo "LINENO: ${LINENO}"
    echo "BASH_LINENO: ${BASH_LINENO[*]}"
}

function foo() {
    log "$@"
}

foo "$@"
```

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) for details of Bash variables.

Answer (score 10):

PS4 with value $LINENO is what you need,

E.g. Following script (myScript.sh):

```
       #!/bin/bash -xv
       PS4='${LINENO}: '
       echo "Hello"
       echo "World"
```

Output would be:

```
  ./myScript.sh
  +echo Hello
  3 : Hello
  +echo World
  4 : World
```

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 5):

### Workaround for shells without LINENO

In a fairly sophisticated script I wouldn't like to see all line numbers; rather I would like to be in control of the output.

Define a function

```
echo_line_no () {
    grep -n "$1" $0 |  sed "s/echo_line_no//" 
    # grep the line(s) containing input $1 with line numbers
    # replace the function name with nothing 
} # echo_line_no
```

Use it with quotes like

```
echo_line_no "this is a simple comment with a line number"
```

Output is

```
16   "this is a simple comment with a line number"
```

if the number of this line in the source file is 16.

This basically answers the question [How to show line number when executing bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804007/how-to-show-line-number-when-executing-bash-script) for users of ash or other shells without `LINENO`.

Anything more to add?

Sure. Why do you need this? How do you work with this? What can you do with this? Is this simple approach really sufficient or useful? Why do you want to tinker with this at all?

Want to know more? [Read reflections on debugging](https://kklepper.github.io/Workaround-for-shells-without-LINENO/#digression-debugging-table-of-content)

Answer (score 1):

Simple (but powerful) solution: Place `echo` around the code you think that causes the problem and move the `echo` line by line until the messages does not appear anymore on screen - because the script has stop because of an error before.

Even more powerful solution: Install [`bashdb`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) the bash debugger and debug the script line by line

Comment: `echo`ing stuff around can help in many cases, but falls short when you try to apply it in functions that has meaningful, parseable output.

Comment: @EliranMalka Fair point. You may echo to stderr in that case: `echo "foo" >&2`

Comment: ...one should echo to stderr in _all_ cases when the purpose is messages that are diagnostic in nature.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `$LINENO` within a function, it will cache the first occurrence. Instead use `${BASH_LINENO[0]}`