# How can I verify my cron job will run using Ubuntu on AWS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a `crontab` file located at `/usr/bin/crontab`.

It's supposed to run every day at 7:30a est. I don't want to have to wait hours to see if it runs. Aside from changing the time it runs, are there other places I can look to ensure that the script will run at the desired time? I basically want to ensure the crontab file has been loaded in

Thanks!

Edit: When I `vi /etc/spool/cron/crontabs`, I see

```
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   crontabs
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
~
~
```

Comment: Don't edit the master crontab. Instead, use `crontab -e` to edit your *personal* crontab.

Comment: @wildplasser, what OP try to edit is directory where cron records are stored

Comment: Yes, but that is not what he *should* be doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5837615/608639), [How to test a weekly cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4984725/608639), [Verify if crontab works](https://askubuntu.com/q/85558), [Running a cron job manually and immediately](https://serverfault.com/q/85893), [Manually run a cron job / simulate running cron job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49419), [How can I make cron run a job right now, for testing/debugging? without changing the schedule!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42715), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the spool directory for awaiting cron jobs.

The location of cron files for individual users is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`

From man crontab:

> Each user can have their own crontab, and though these are files in /var/spool/cron/crontabs, they are not intended to be edited directly.

If it's there it will run.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute command

```
crontab -l
```

This will list all cron records for your user
Also you can check if cron daemon is run

```
ps -efl|grep cron
```

With this command you can check (postfactum) what is the result of cron execution

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

You can't easy speedup the things, just wait till desired time. Or schedule the same job to be executed 10-15 minutes after your current time.

P.S. And `/etc/spool/cron/crontabs` is directory. See the top of this answer